# Can you safely put a different size orifice on a gas stove burner?

Tags: propane, orifice

While converting a gas stove to lp, I dropped the 5,000btu orifice into the stove top. I can't lift the lid without voiding the warranty on this brand new stove. Can I safely put a 9,500btu orifice in it's place?

Comment: Changing the orifice to a larger one would probably void the warranty too. Get the right size from the vendor.

Comment: Thank you for the info.